# Existence or nonexistence of semilinear Poisson equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

Suppose that $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is a bounded domain with smooth boundary $\partial\Omega$. Consider the following semilinear Poisson equation with prescribed Dirichlet data on the boundary:
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
%\vspace{3mm}
-\Delta \phi=\frac{1}{\phi}\quad \text{in}\quad\hspace{2.5mm} \Omega,\\
\hspace{7mm}\phi=0 \hspace{6mm} \text{on}\quad \partial\Omega.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

How to investigate existence or nonexistence of solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problems of this type are called **Singular elliptic equations**.
There is a big variety of methods how you can obtain solutions. Try to look [here](http://books.google.de/books?hl=ru&lr=&id=Mlp_g5TdIt8C&oi=fnd&pg=PA317&dq=Singular%20Elliptic%20and%20Parabolic%20Equations&ots=P7eqsq7y1P&sig=seDnReO9tzLBQCZ_wRLwtaFcpUk&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Singular%20Elliptic%20and%20Parabolic%20Equations&f=false)  and [here](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0517096).

Comment: Thank you very much for the information! I did not know it belongs to the class of singular elliptic equations.